# Samsung laptop: data recovery after system recovery

Tags: laptop, data-recovery

I have Samsung np550-p5c laptop. After purchase I shrunk the Windows partition and created second one for my data. Yesterday I tried to recover Windows with native F4 recovery. Recovery went well except for one thing: my data partition became marked as "recovery". So I have two "recovery" partitions shown in Disk Management. Your opinion: was the partition reformatted while recovering? Anyone had similar problem? Is there a way to recover whole partition and/or data?

Comment: Are you trying to recover data from a system after having used the recovery process to restore it to factory condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's any data on the disk you care about, take an image of all the data on the disk and save it for recovery. To restore the system, remove the first two partitions, create one partition out of the free space, and run the factory recovery again.

What happened is the factory recovery attempted to restore the laptop to factory conditions. It recovered the first partition to the factory Windows installation and it recovered the second partition to the factory recovery partition. It left the third partition alone.

Comment: What you say makes sence. But I would be less surprized if it just destroyed my data partition and recovered everything, including partition layout. How can I work effectively with my HDD without fear of losing data after recovery? Do I have to choose between possibility of factory reset and manual partitioning?

Comment: If you have any data you want to recovery, make an image of the hard drive immediately. That way, you can attempt recovery several different ways without fear of harming any saveable data.

Comment: I see. I've restored everything important without any problems. The main question stays: is there any way to make sure this will never happen again?

Comment: 1) Don't run the factory recovery process on a drive that contains data you care about. 2) Keep data you care about in at least two places.

Comment: I suppose by drive you mean hdd device, not the partition? Well, I'll have to forget about factory reset and use some third-party recovery solution. Thanks anyway.